# Account Handling Scenario

Tags: account

I have a scenario that is bugging me and I need to solve it. This is for a new SF implementation and we are just planning out the Account handling.

The idea is to use the regular Lead -> Account/Contact conversion. That flow solved our first issue of having Leads becoming buyer for other persons, as in Jon Doe father buys items for himself as well as for his family.

That would be:

Jon Lead is converted, ends up with Jon Account (buyer) and 1 contact per Person receiving his items. So I get Jon Account (father/buyer) and Rick (son) and Maria (daughter) as Contacts under that Account.

This is ok, the scenario I am having trouble wrapping my head around is the following:

I have a corporate Account I sell too, say "Marvelous Licenses", they buy many licenses for their employees. I have a Contact per each employee receiving a license from this company, they are under that Account.

One of the Employees, say Mike, wants to buy licenses for his family, what do I do with this guy?. Should I have a separate Account for him so he can buy for his family?, what seems weird to me here is that his actual Contact will point to the corporate Account, and he will have no Contact representing himself under his buyer Account, because he is already a contact of the corporate one.

As I said, I still haven't come up with a solution to this scenario so any idea is welcome :)

Cheers and thanks  for the help!.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input, both answers that I received aimed at the same solution, which was the right for my needs. I think I have to mark only one as correct answer so I marked the one that I understood easier, but both answers were great!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, you can use Contact Roles. Choose which type of relationship will be your primary relationship (either Contact -> Household Account or Contact -> Corporate Account), and use Contact Roles for the secondary relationship. If you're primarily in a B2C environment, make your primary account relationship the household relationship. Contact Roles let you define secondary relationships with your contacts and accounts. This would leave you with something like this:

```
Mike Account                    Jon Account
           \                      /    <-- Contact's Account
    Mike Contact             Jon Contact
             \                  /    <-- Contact Roles
              Marvelous Licenses
```

This way, you can show both the primary and secondary relationships.

Also, vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBSAA0) in regards to allowing native first-class multiple account relationships on contacts.

Answer (score 3):

Accounts in this scenario can represent households and companies. I recommend a creating a record type to handle this distinction. However, you only get one Account Name (AccountId) lookup field from Contact to Account and I don't recommend overloading this lookup with more than one relationship type. The Account Name should either always represent the Household relationship or always represent the employer/employee relationship, but not both.

I would choose the more prevalent relationship (household or employer) to your business and use the Account Name field to represent that relationship. If it is household that you choose, you will likely need some code to automatically create and assign a household for every contact you create, if an Account Name is not provided. On the flip side, if you choose employer as the primary Account Name relationship, you may need some code to handle dumping contacts with unknown employers into a bucket account of some sort.

For the other relationship, I recommend creating a separate lookup field. In other words, if Account Name represent a household, create a lookup on Contact to Account called Employer.

While this scenario creates some burden to auto-populate this Account Name field in instances where you either don't know or don't care about this relationship for a contact, it keeps your reporting clear and concise without any question about what a relationship represents.